# Get place in result on query with join MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the place of an result in my query avoiding the same number of double results.
The results are the rank of user in my table.
My problem is when I have 2 or more users with the same score. Than they will have the same rank.
This my query right now:

```
SELECT users.user_name, us.score, COUNT(mrank.id) as rank
  FROM user users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN challenges_score_user_rel us
    ON us.user_id = users.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN challenges_score_user_rel mrank
    ON mrank.score >= us.score
 GROUP BY users.id
 ORDER BY rank DESC
```

For example: If 2 users have the most scores and that amount is equal they both will have the rank 2.

Comment: how should the rank be determined when multiple users have the same score?

Comment: The rank should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will break ties by giving the user with the greater user_id the greater rank

```
SELECT users.user_name, us.score,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM challenges_score_user_rel us2
    WHERE (us2.score < us.score OR us2.user_id = us.user_id)
    OR (us2.score = us.score AND us.user_id < us2.user_id)) rank
FROM user users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN challenges_score_user_rel us
    ON us.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

same query as a self join

```
SELECT users.user_name, us.score, COUNT(*) rank
FROM user users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN challenges_score_user_rel us
    ON us.user_id = users.id
JOIN challenges_score_user_rel us2
    ON (us2.score < us.score OR us2.user_id = us.user_id)
    OR (us2.score = us.score AND us.user_id < us2.user_id)
GROUP BY users.user_name, us.score    
ORDER BY rank  DESC
```